# Spring mvc unable to use form:select for object list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having problem when I try to render some object from controller to view, I have a role list object which I want to render in view as a combo box using  tag in spring mvc but having following problem :
02:57:31,498 ERROR SelectTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'role' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'role' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundF

My controller is look like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/assignFeatureToRole" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String assignFeatureToRole(ModelMap model){
    List<Role> roles = roleAssignerService.findAllRoles();
    model.addAttribute("roles", roles);     
    return "roleWiseFeatureAssignment";
}
```

and my view is

```
<form:select path="role" >
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                <form:options items="${roles}" />
            </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution

```
<form:select path="roles" >
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                <form:options items="${roles}" itemLabel="roleDesc" itemValue="roleId"/>
            </form:select>
```

My mistake was I use path="role" instead of path="roles", it is perfectly rendering.